# Java - new hashCode method

Tags: java, hashcode

I should override with several changes the method hashCode() for a array with length 500.
Each array index (for example array[499]) must contains exactly 35512 object.

I work with String of length 6 like that : "character character character number number number" (e.g "ABX015"). I must write a method hasdcode for every String like it (from "AAA000" to "ZZZ999" )

I wrote this :

```
public int hashCode() {
return ((Math.abs(myStringName.hashCode()) %499);
}
```

The only problem is that I got differents values depending which index I use.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this. What does "Each array index must contains exactly 35512 object" mean? Or any of the rest of it, for that matter. Is it a class containing an array of Strings of length 500, each of length 6, with three letters and three numbers?

Comment: Whichever index you choose between 0 and 499, I should have the same value  (e.g array[399] = 35512 ). I must separe the 17576000 possibilities into 500 list (I use for instead only a array with the number of add in the choose index (e.g  array[325] = 35400)

Comment: What could the purpose of such an array possibly be? In any case, 35512 is not an object, it's an int, and you can't override the hashCode() method of an array.

Comment: The aim is to separate the 17576000 possibilities into 500 list but 35512 in one list. hashcode gives me the arrayIndex where I must put my string

Comment: Like this : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_p3DfNPWRXdY/THGpoPu4ERI/AAAAAAAAADc/UWK3P9NAMkQ/s1600/hashTable.png but with the  35512 objects and the objects are String with the format I explained

Comment: The graphic you linked to suggests you're implementing a hash table, but how can you talk on the one hand about the "array index where I must put my string" and at the same time "array[399] = 35512". Either you are putting strings into the array, or ints. Why don't you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're hashing 6-char String values that starts with 3 letters and end in 3 numbers. You want to create a hash for all 17576000 possible combinations and have them fall between 0 and 499, and all be equally distributed across this range of hashes. You want it so you can create an array of size 500 that counts collisions. And what you expect is array[*] = 35152 (since 17576000 / 500 = 35152).

Do I understand that correctly?

Either way, here's the easy solution I came up with:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int num = Integer.valueOf(myStringName.substring(3));
    return num / 2;
}
```

You **know** that the last three are going to be 0-999. Just divide that by 2 and use that as your hash.